# Data reconciliation for applications

Tags: backup, synchronization, data-recovery, attacks

I need to create a plan for a catastrophic data loss scenario where I need to recover some services (multiple apps each) from bare metal using data backups.
The process (i believe) requires the following:

1. Recover binaries and data from the backup. Instal App. (Easy bit)
2. Applications are interdependent and need to be synced - different backup times mean I may need to roll back data for some applications.
3. Identify sources for lost data (data lost from recovery point till time of the incident)
4. Reconcile lost data
5. Reconcile buffered transactions and workaround data (any data collected during the applications were down)
6. Validate and return to BaU

It is steps 4 and 5 that are slightly troublesome where i want your help. I understand it would depend on the application type and what it does, but is there any guidance or ideas that could make my life easier? Some tool or lessons learned from your experience?

Regards,

Comment: We are not here to do your job when you lack the qualification to do so. Also, this is a VERY complex theme - one that requires compromises, and I am not putting in the time without knowing requirements, limits of negotiation and the exact technologies used. The question is totally open due to the TOTAL lack of ANY relevant information. I suggest hiring someone competent to do this job.

Comment: No offense taken - it literally is not my job to do this - I am however accountable for this. You are quite right, I don't have the quals, hence the ask for overarching guidance for pitfall and not the exact answer.

Comment: The problem is that the devil is in the detail, we do not recommend i.e. tools and tools may be specific to the technology you use (off topic), and those tools may be specific to the technologies you use.. Also, any complex backup scheme does incur compromises that MUST be discussed and are way too large for this here. Really, hire a professional.